# Why are the vote count boxes different sizes for some posts in the search results?

Tags: support, search

When performing a search on Stack Overflow, I noticed that some posts are displayed with large vote count boxes next to them, and some are displayed with small vote count boxes.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A508666

I don't see why this is happening. What is the difference between the two posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because some of them are *questions* and some of them are *answers*.

The questions display larger vote count boxes, because they have to display the total number of votes on the question itself, as well as the total number of answers that have been posted.

The answers only need to display the number of votes that the answer has received, so the box can be made smaller.

[image: Questions have larger vote count boxes]

[image: Answers have smaller vote count boxes]